# Showing that a measurable function defined on a certain measure set is constant a.e

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X=\mathbb R$ with sigma algebra $\mathcal S=\{A\subset \mathbb R:A\text{ or }A^c\text{ is countable }\}$. Let $\mu$ be the measure on $X$ defined by $\mu(A)=0$ if $A$ is countable and $\mu(A)=2$ if $A^c$ is countable.

Let $f:X\rightarrow\mathbb R$ be a measurable function. **Show that $f$ is a constant almost every where.**

I have been given the following hint:

1. Show that there is an $n\in\mathbb Z$ such that $f^{-1}[n,n+1]$ is uncountable.
2. If there are 2 such integers say $m<n$ then $n=m+1$ and $(f^{-1}\{n\})^c$ is countable. So $f=n$ a.e
3. If $n$ is unique, then divide $[n,n+1]$ into 2 and repeat the procedure of step 2. If this process doesn't terminate at a finite stage then we get a decreasing sequence of compact sets whose measure tends to 0. Their intersection is a single point say $\{a\}$ and $f=a$ a.e.

I understand the first and third step and am able to proceed with the proof of the result assuming the second. However, I don't know how to prove the second step. If someone can hep me that would be great.

If there is a different way to solve this problem, that would also be nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $n >m+1$ then $A=f^{-1} [n, n+1]$ and $B=f^{-1} [m, m+1]$ are disjoint sets whose complements are countable. Hence $\mathbb R=A^{c} \cup B^{c}$ is countable which is  a contradiction. Hence $n \leq m+1$ and $m <n$  so $n=m+1$. Now $f^{-1} [m, m+1]$ and $f^{-1} [m+1, m+1]$ both have countable complements so their intersection has countable complement. This means $\{x: f(x) \neq m+1\}$ is countable. Since countable sets have measure $0$ it follows that $f=m+1$ a.e..

Comment: Thank you. However, this relies heavily on there being exactly two integers $m$ and $n$. That means the problem requires an extra step to say there cannot be more than 2 integers for which $f^{-1}[n,n+1]$ is uncountable. Or am I missing something?

Comment: If you have more than two such  integers then you will have sets $A, B$ such that the complements of $f^{-1}(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$ are both countable. But that makes $\mathbb R$ countable as in my proof.  [Only two intervals of the type $[n,n+1]$ can have a point in common].  @R_D

Comment: Oh yes I got it now. Thank you